# How does the architecture for a web app using rdf and sparql in java look like?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena

I'm familiar with the basics of the business logic of a web app, but I don't know how to start a project using apache jena. Where should I write the RDF, where SPARQL, frontend ...?

Comment: that is the wrong question for StackOverflow - I mean, it sounds like you do not even know why to use Semantic Web technologies at all, right? Why do you want to use RDF and SPARQL? What are the benefits for your application? What does your application?

Comment: In addition, Apache Jena provides an RDF database (aka triple store) and a HTTP accessible SPARQL server. So where to store the RDF data and how to query it is exactly the same as using a relation database - and you should know where in your application you want to use that database and for what. Frontend is just web UI stuff, I don't see any relation to RDF in that regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the RDF triple store (whichever one you use, see below) as your database, RDF lives there, and SPARQL is your query language to communicate between the database and your back-end logic. Libraries/frameworks like Jena and RDF4J give you a way to make SPARQL queries and then iterate over the results.

For your triple store you can use the solutions that come with Jena and RDF4J (e.g., Fuseki2) or some other graph database such as Amazon Neptune or Ontotext GraphDB. I would recommend starting with the ones that come with the libraries, and later "graduate" to the more serious offerings.